# Небезопасные правила в fireBase

Tags: firebase, realtime, rules

В моем простом приложении только контент загружается с fireBase, авторизации у меня нет. Постоянно приходит письмо от Гугл, что - В базе данных Realtime Database обнаружены небезопасные правила, к тому же с такими правилами я проработаю не больше месяца( Как мне нужно настроить правила безопасности для моего случая?

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```